# Looking for proper join (getting duplicates)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with creating the query. But before I ask you about them, please have a look on three tables I need to use:

Table_1 // AdminInvoices

```
[AdminId] [InvoiceId] (...)
```

Table_2 // AdminClientSystem

```
[AdminId] [ClientId] (...)
```

Table_3 // ClientData

```
[CompanyId] [CompanyName] (...)
```

Some more notes about tables:

Table_1

InvoiceId is int not unique in general, but for Company i.e:

```
AdminId     InvoiceId
16              1
14              1
24              1
3149            1
3150            1
3159            2
3157            2
3150            2
3149            2
3145            2
16              3
14              3
24              3
2015            3
3149            3
3159            4
3157            4
3150            4
```

Table_2:

```
AdminId       CompanyId
3                 1
3                 1
3                 1
3                 1
3                 1
3                 1
3                 2
3                 2
3                 3
3                 4
3                 4
3                 4
3                 9
3                 9
3                 9
3                 9
3                 9
3                 9
3                 9
3                 9
3                 13
3                 13
3                 13
```

Table_3:

```
CompanyId   CompanyName
1              C1
2              C2
3              C3
9              C4
13             C5
```

I have a problem with creating proper query with join. In my case, I have always got redundant data as answer. What I would like to get is **the number of Invoices per Company**.

Let's say that I am sure that C1 had generated 100 invoices, C2 50 and C3 200. Whatever query I make the numbers are about twice or even more bigger - some rows from other tables are getting copied to general result.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT CL.CompanyName, count([IncentiveId]) 
FROM AdminInvoices
INNER JOIN AdminClientSystem
  ON AdminInvoices.AdminId = AdminClientSystem.AdminId
INNER JOIN ClientData
  ON AdminClientSystem.CompanyId = ClientData.CompanyId
GROUP BY CL.CompanyName
ORDER BY CL.CompanyName ASC
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Am I right considering it as SQL and not mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS far as i can see in your Example, AdminClientSystem has many redundant entries, so for one adminid you got several entries with a company id. Not sure if the table has really data this way, or you just posted something wrong.
To only use them once, you can use a subquery, like:

```
 SELECT CL.CompanyName, count([IncentiveId]) 
 FROM AdminInvoices
 INNER JOIN (select distinct AdminId, CompanyId from AdminClientSystem) as ACS
 ON AdminInvoices.AdminId = ACS.AdminId
 INNER JOIN ClientData
 ON ACS.CompanyId= ClientData.CompanyId
 GROUP BY CL.CompanyName
 ORDER BY CL.CompanyName ASC
```

Comment: I will try it in a sec, and yes - AdminClientSystem has a lot redundant data in first two columns, other columns in the table differ.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 SELECT CL.CompanyName, count([AdminInvoices.InvoiceId]) 
 FROM AdminInvoices 
 INNER JOIN 
 (select distinct(AdminId),CompanyId  
 from AdminClientSystem 
 WHERE CompanyId IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT CompanyId FROM ClientData)) as ACS
 ON AdminInvoices.AdminId = ACS.AdminId
 INNER JOIN ClientData as CL
 ON ACS.CompanyId= CL.CompanyId
 GROUP BY CL.CompanyName
```